# Lua Patterns and Unicode

Tags: unicode, lua, lua-patterns, world-of-warcraft

What would be the best way to find a word such as Hi or a name mainly like dön with that special char in it through a pattern. They would be optional so it should obviously use a '?' but I dont know what control code to use to find them.

I basically want to make sure that I am getting words with possible unicode characters in them but nothing else. So dön would be fine but no other special chars or numbers and such like brackets.

Comment: The support to Unicode of Lua (5.2 or earlier) is rather limited in genereal. Post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what exactly you want to solve, there is perhaps a easy way to solve it, perhaps there's not.

Comment: Ok the simplist example I can give is I need a lua pattern that can return words with special characters in them. BUT they dont have to have special characters. If this is possible how would I do this?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Lua guide on Unicode](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaUnicode), "Lua's pattern matching facilities work byte by byte. In general, this will not work for Unicode pattern matching, although some things will work as you want". This means the best option is probably to iterate over each character and work out if it is a valid letter. To loop over each unicode character in a string:

```
for character in string.gmatch(myString, "([%z\1-\127\194-\244][\128-\191]*)") do
    -- Do something with the character
end
```

Note this method will not work if `myString` isn't valid unicode. To check if the character is one that you want, it's probably best to simply have a list of all characters you don't want in your strings and then exclude them:

```
local notAllowed = ":()[]{}+_-=\|`~,.<>/?!@#$%^&*"
local isValid = true

for character in string.gmatch(myString, "([%z\1-\127\194-\244][\128-\191]*)") do
    if notAllowed:find(character) then
        isValid = false
        break
    end
end
```

Hope this helped.